# Freemarker Template Error

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, freemarker

When i am hitting the login button and it is redirect to the hello.ftl page after successfull login through database. But the ftl page shows this error

> FreeMarker template error (DEBUG mode; use RETHROW in production!):
>   The following has evaluated to null or missing: ==> var [in template
>   "hello.ftl" at line 8, column 32] ---- Tip: If the failing expression
>   is known to be legally refer to something that's sometimes null or
>   missing, either specify a default value like myOptionalVar!myDefault,
>   or use <#if myOptionalVar??>when-present<#else>when-missing. (These
>   only cover the last step of the expression; to cover the whole
>   expression, use parenthesis: (myOptionalVar.foo)!myDefault,
>   (myOptionalVar.foo)?? ---- ---- FTL stack trace ("~" means
>   nesting-related): - Failed at: #macro url relativeUrl extra... [in
>   template "spring.ftl" in macro "url" at line 89, column 1] - Reached
>   through: @spring.url "/logout", var = "logoutUrl" [in template
>   "hello.ftl" at line 8, column 9] ---- Java stack trace (for
>   programmers): ---- freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: [...
>   Exception message was already printed; see it above ...] at
>   freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException.getInstance(InvalidReferenceException.java:134)
>   at freemarker.core.EvalUtil.compare(EvalUtil.java:196) at
>   freemarker.core.EvalUtil.compare(EvalUtil.java:113) at
>   freemarker.core.ComparisonExpression.evalToBoolean(ComparisonExpression.java:62)
>   at freemarker.core.BooleanExpression._eval(BooleanExpression.java:30)
>   at freemarker.core.Expression.eval(Expression.java:81) at

```
<#import "/spring.ftl" as spring>
<html>
<body>

    Welcome
    <!-- For login user --> 

    <@spring.url '/logout' var="logoutUrl"/>


    <form action="${logoutUrl}" method="post" id="logoutForm">
            <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
                value="${_csrf.token}" />
        </form>

        <script>
            function formSubmit() {
                document.getElementById("logoutForm").submit();
            }
        </script>

        <#if "${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name != null}"?? >
    <span><h2>
                User : ${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name} | <a
                    href="javascript:formSubmit()"> Logout</a>
            </h2></span>
        </#if>


</body>
</html>
```

Please tell me the solution, why this code is not working

Comment: i have added logout code in this hello.ftl page but it gives me freemarker template error. Please look the code and tell me the solution

Answer (score 0):

It tries to interpret `var="logoutUrl"` as `var == "logoutUrl"`, and thus looks for a variable called `var`. To avoid that, all parameters must be passed by name:

```
<@spring.url relativeUrl='/logout' var="logoutUrl"/>
```

Though given the extra parameter name and value I'm not sure what you meant to achieve with this. Maybe you just wanted `<@spring.url logoutUrl />`?